# Pulling data associated with user account in Django

Tags: django, rest, model

I'm creating a model in Django with the following syntax. The model has a foreign key of registered users. However, I want to serialize this model that will return a JSON file only associated with the logged in user. Can you give your recommendations? Or is there an alternative way to extract the information from the model using different approach?

```
class Education(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      school = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      year = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Sample photo:

[image]

For instance, it will only show the first field associated with the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter objects related to a user, simply get hold of the user and apply filter based on the user.

`user_education_queryset = Education.objects.filter(user=user)`

if you are doing this in the view where user objects is available in request context, you could simply do `user=request.user` Note: the user has to be logged in, else this will return anonymouse user object which will fail to query the database.

Summary:
Get the user object and filter by the user field in education model using the user object obtained.
`mike = User.objects.get(id=1) # or mike = User.objects.get(username='mike')`
then
`mike_education_query = Education.objects.filter(user=mike)`

Comment: This is really helpful! I am able to query the results by user.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the suggestions, I was able to query the results per user with this code:

```
class EducationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EducationSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        account = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
        return Education.objects.filter(user=account)
```